# Decide redirection for Invalid Session in Spring security

Tags: session, spring-security

I have setup Spring Security on my webapp project.

My application setting for session expiration time is 15 min.

The spring security config is pretty basic and I have

```
<http use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">

    <csrf />

    <intercept-url pattern="/login/auth" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/about" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/contact-us" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" requires-channel="any"/>

    <session-management invalid-session-url="/?invalidSession=1"
                        session-authentication-error-url="/login?session=fail"
                        session-fixation-protection="migrateSession">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"
                             expired-url="/login?invalidSession=1"/>
    </session-management>
```

Now the problem I'm having is that for example given the user sends an invalid session id spring always redirects to the homepage with '/?invalidSession=1'.

I'm saying it is a problem due to the fact that if the user, after a certain period of time, tries for example to go to the /contact-us page (which us an unprotected resource) he gets redirected to the homepage.

I think one solution would be that spring creates a new session and then redirects to the previously requested resource instead of always the invalid-session-url.

How do you deal with these situations?

Comment: If the contact-us is a unprotected resource it should be in a different http element that doesn't include session management.

Comment: Are you suggesting to create a second <http> element containing all unprotected resources without a <session - management> element? Should I then move all the resources with access="permitAll" to the new http element?

Comment: No just the about and contact-us. You can add 2 http elements. `<http pattern="/contact-us" security="none" />`.

Comment: In contact-us page I've parts using the security taglib to display the logged-in username on the header for example. When adding those resources as separate with security="none" filters are skipped and all the parts using security functionality don't work anymore.

Comment: I ended up removing invalid-session-url="/?invalidSession=1" completely form my configuration in order to not have Spring Security failing on a invalid SessionID sent from the client